# Open two tabs side by side on Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, windows-10, internet, window, productivity

I need to open two tabs side by side on Chrome in most of the cases. Currently what I do is open up a new Chrome window and use it side by side with the original one. **I just need to do the same thing using a single/one Chrome window**. I like to do it without installing any extensions on Chrome, but if there aren’t any solid solutions, then I will think about an extension.

Please suggest me a solution, I don't hesitate to play with the windows registry or get any other risk to try this out.

Comment: Do you want 2 tabs side by side **within one chrome window** so that when you drag the window, both the tabs will remain side by side next to each other?

Comment: There's a Google Chrome extension that allows this.
It's called "Tab Resize - split screen layouts" "https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tab-resize-split-screen-l/bkpenclhmiealbebdopglffmfdiilejc/related"

Comment: Seems it just creates multiple windows.

Comment: @thilinaR, Apologies for the (very) delayed response. Yes, that's exactly what I try to achieve here. I do have a 4K monitor and I am big fan of organizing my applications windows all over the place on the screen and changing them according to different situations. This is a really important feature to me.

Comment: @Nesar, Yes - It creates multiple windows, but it is a useful plugin. Thank you.

Answer (score 14):

There is no way of having two tabs embedded side by side in the chrome interface. Your current solution would be made easier by the use of keyboard shortcuts:

1. WinKey+left arrow to snap chrome to left side of screen
2. Ctrl+N to open a new Chrome Window
3. WinKey+right arrow to snap new chrome instance to right side of screen

Answer (score -3):

i found an easier way to display 2 web pages side by side,from desktop with no browser open simply press browser button twice,abit like double clicking and it will open two browser pages,just minimize both and resize to fit screen side by side

Answer (score -3):

Pretty much the same thing as Andrew, but right click then new window works too. A bit easier for me, personally, to remember.